# Are telescope questions not considered space exploration?

Tags: discussion, scope

I came across this question: [What type of telescope should I use in order to view the surface of the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/what-type-of-telescope-should-i-use-in-order-to-view-the-surface-of-the-moon?rq=1) which got closed for being off-topic.

And I'm wondering, are telescopes **not** considered a form of space exploration on this site? Why or why not? I think telescopes, whether on the ground or in a space probe, can be considered exploring space. A lot of discoveries about our solar system and the universe were made by them, and I think they've also proven vital in gathering enough information to prepare our probes as much as possible so that they maximize their scientific return.

Answer (score 6):

The question was closed as off-topic because it really belonged on [Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/). Ordinarily it would have been migrated there, together with all its comments and answers. At the time this question was asked Astronomy had not yet gone live, though. It opened in early October 2013, about two months after this question. By that time the question was too old to migrate, and it would already have been a duplicate there anyhow, so it has sat here. Space Exploration was also so young at the time that moderators hadn't yet been appointed, so this question also has the unique characteristic of having apparently been closed by two moderators, not just one. If this question was a coin, it would be highly collectible. :)

Several questions of this type exist on Astronomy.SE:

[Telescope buying guide for a beginner in India](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1273/2810)
[Should I focus more on Aperture or Focal Length for a telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/534/2810)
[Best telescope for the viewing of Nebulae, Stars and Planets](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2193/2810)

Here is the stated scope there:

> Astronomy Stack Exchange is a Question and Answer site about astronomy
>   and astronomy related topics; the study of objects and matter outside
>   the Earth's atmosphere and of their physical and chemical properties
>
> The purpose of this site is to provide expert level answers to
>   questions on:
>
> - Setting up, using and maintaining your astronomy related equipment
> - Astronomical observations, for all celestial objects across the entire spectral range.
> - Astrophysics and Cosmology
> - Planetary Science and Celestial mechanics
> - Data returned by space missions such as probes, rovers and satellites
> - What type of equipment will allow you to see a certain entity

Though there was a comment that cited the product recommendation issue, it doesn't seem to me that it applied - the question asked about the *type* of telescope to buy. The one answer that exists gives a bit of commentary on that, and much more information could have been offered about relevant telescope characteristics without any mention of brands or models.

Comment: Note that questions about planetary science, and data returned by spacecraft, often occur here on Space Exploration - our scope includes 'Scientific discoveries made by space probes'. So there is overlap.

Answer (score 1):

The question is off-topic because it is a product recommendation, which is [off-topic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), as noted in an upvoted comment to the very question you asked that was closed.